# Load balancing MQTT Client

Tags: java, mqtt, paho

Originally my setup is having a threadpool to consume subscribe messages.

Is it possible to load balance MQTT?

I found these https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mqtt/kUgBFgBmcGk , but seems like its dead.

Comment: What exactly do you mean in the second sentence? Do you mean split a subscription across multiple clients?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thread pool pattern is usual approach to this as it allows the actual MQTT client get back to either handling the next incoming message or finishing the QOS handshake as quickly as possible.

Some brokers support a new feature in the MQTT 3.1.1 spec called [*Shared Subscriptions*](https://issues.oasis-open.org/browse/MQTT-234) which allow multiple clients to consume messages in a distributed fashion.

IBM's [MessageSight](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSCGGQ_1.2.0/com.ibm.ism.doc/Developing/devsharedsubscriptions.html) appliance supports Shared Subscriptions. I'm not sure if any of the other available brokers have this support yet, but I would expect at least some to add it.

** Full disclosure -> I work for IBM

Comment: wow, is this exclusive only for ibm? because im actually using paho mqtt and I use the asynchronous way of pub/sub.

Comment: I believe it's on the public spec, so anybody is free to implement it, I'm just not aware of any other brokers having done it yet

Comment: Actually Shared Subscriptions are not in the MQTT 3.1.1 spec. MessageSight and HiveMQ both support Shared Subscriptions with slightly different semantics. See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSCGGQ_1.2.0/com.ibm.ism.doc/Developing/devsharedsubscriptions.html and http://www.hivemq.com/docs/hivemq/latest/#hivemqdocs_shared_subscriptions

Comment: actually also vernemq support shared queries and it is opensource https://vernemq.com/docs/configuration/shared_subscriptions.html

Comment: Shared subscriptions is a feature of the MQTT 5.0 spec, all implementation at 3.x level are implementation specific so not likely to work if you change broker

Comment: I think that for me is a design error, if I scale horizontally, every node will subscribe to topics and then update database after receiving a message. I think that mqtt is not the best solution, but I need to receive messages from an arduino, maybe I need a different way to communicate between arduino and backend application

Comment: With shared subscriptions each message is only delivered to one client